# ¿Cuáles son todos los significados de la interjección ah?

Tags: interjecciones

Estaba viendo un video sobre Japonés sobre la interjección a, aa del Japonés, que tiene practicamente los mismos significados que nuestra interjección ah. Busqué en RAE y no encontré una definición pero en Google me sale esto:

> 1. Indica que el que habla se ha dado cuenta de algo o lo ha comprendido.
>    "¡ah!, entonces tú no estabas"

> 2. Indica admiración, sorpresa o pena.

[Ah Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=ah%20&source=hp&ei=j2wHY7jTGd7Q1sQP-P-COA&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYwd6n9iWlyajpHbgF4yUdmeiGkITZt09&ved=0ahUKEwj41v3BgOL5AhVeqJUCHfi_AAcQ4dUDCAc&uact=5&oq=ah%20&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCQgAEEMQRhD5ATIECAAQQzIUCC4QgAQQsQMQgwEQxwEQrwEQ1AIyBAgAEEMyBAguEEMyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyCwgAEIAEELEDEIMBMgQILhBDMgQIABBDOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARDRA1AAWLMCYLgEaABwAHgAgAGNAYgBiwKSAQMwLjKYAQCgAQE&sclient=gws-wiz)

Que son los mismos significados que mostraban en el video en Japonés, sin embargo en el video había algunas otras como por ejemplo, enojo. Creo que nosotros también usamos el ahh!? para enojo, y tal vez para otras emociones. Por eso mi pregunta era,

¿Cuáles son todos los significados o emociones que expresa la interjección ah en Español?

Answer (score 0):

El DRAE dice:

**ah**

1. interj. U. para denotar pena, admiración, sorpresa o sentimientos similares.
2. interj. Am. U. para interrogar.

Todo depende, obviamente, de la entonación:

A. Se me murió el perro.
B. **Ah**, qué pena.

A. Gané la lotería.
B. ¡**Ah**, qué bueno! (admiración, sorpresa "positiva")

A. Pisaste una cucaracha.
B. ¡**Ah**, qué asco! (sorpresa "negativa")

A. Me equivoqué en la cuenta.
B. **Ah**, ahora entiendo.

Con interrogación, se puede usar para instar a una respuesta:

A. No voy a ir.
B. ¿**Ah**? (La persona da a entender que espera una aclaración, o detalles.)

Answer (score 0):

**¡Ah!**

---

De las distintas capacidades que el ser humano tiene para experimentar y expresarse, la RAE recoge en su definición de ***ah!*** como interjección, las siguientes, ***ah!*** para interrogar, para denotar ***pena***, ***admiración***, ***sorpresa*** o **sentimientos similares**.

https://dle.rae.es/ah

Con esta nota singular hacia "**sentimientos similares**" entendemos la existencia de otros, considerados análogos, aunque la Real Academia no los incluya o especifique.

---

En el antiguo diccionario latino ***Ah***, como interjección indicaba *varios movimientos del ánimo (facultad de experimentar emociones, afectos, junto a la capacidad de comprender) como dolor, indignación, consuelo, alegría, contracción y significa ah, ai, eh, Ah!. ¡Ay desdichada de mi! Ah, ah, ah, era utilizada como exclamación para explicar la risa*.

---

A primera vista parecería que aquellos que utilizaron el latín tendrían más registros donde aplicar la interjección ***ah!*** que los que la utilizan en nuestros días, sin embargo esto no es así, pues a veces responde a la incapacidad o descuido de algunos diccionarios, en este caso el de la RAE, en una confección lexicográfica pobre que tienen algunas de sus entradas.

Es por ello que más que hacer una enumeración de los distintos significados que pueden tener nuestra interjección ***ah!*** hoy en día, incluida la amplia interpretación de "***sentimientos similares***", he considerado más interesante transcribir algunas notas y conocer cierto trabajo de *Nancy Vázquez* que se ocupa precisamente de esta materia, y que en general puede ser más sugestivo para los amantes de la lengua, pues dentro del análisis de varias expresiones, hay en concreto un estudio de la interjección ***¡ah!***.

---

**Los marcadores discursivos de recepción.**

---

Aja!, Sí!, Uhhuh, Mhm, Ya!, Entiendo!, Entendido!, oh!, **ah!**, Ok... son marcadores discursivos de recepción. Comprenden ruidos, gestos, expresiones, muecas, señales o palabras que sirven para lanzar un mensaje con significado por parte del oyente, dentro de la conversación e interacción oral.

Dentro de las costumbres, hábitos y prácticas de la sociedad que utiliza una lengua, este tipo de marcadores discursivos constituyen un componente importante en el aprendizaje y conocimiento de la población donde se integran. Siendo igualmente particular y necesario cuando se estudia una lengua extranjera, pues algunos sonidos, señales o expresiones pueden ser parecidas o similares a las nuestras y otras que no lo son, lo que en ocasiones puede llevar a malentendidos o equívocos indeseables.

---

[image]

---

*Marcadores discursivos de recepción por Nancy Vázquez Veiga.*

*Universidad de Santiago de Compostela.*

*Servicio de Publicaciones.*

---

**Algunas notas**, páginas 179 y ss.;

> **4. El significado de los marcadores de recepción: Propuesta de descripción Lexicográfica de la Interjección AH**
>
> **4.3.4 Entrada lexicográfica de ah**
>
> ... En el caso de la interjección **ah**, encontramos información
> relevante principalmente en diccionarios y estudios procedentes sobre
> todo del análisis del discurso y de la conversación...
>
> Cuando se habla de diccionarios e interjecciones, los primeros suelen
> salir generalmente malparados por la falta de precisión que
> caracteriza la mayoría de las definiciones de estas UL...
>
> Basta con comparar por ejemplo, la entrada de **ah** que ofrece el
> **Diccionario de la Real Academia Española** (2001) con las que figuran en
> el **Diccionario Salamanca de la lengua española (1996)** y en el
> **Diccionario de español actual (1999)**. En estas dos últimas obras se
> ofrece una delimitación de sentidos mucho más precisa que en el DRAE.
>
> ***¡ah!*** (DISAL) interj. 1. Expresa la emoción o impresión que experimenta
> una persona ante algo. 2. Se usa para mostrar que se entiende, acepta
> o está de acuerdo con lo que se acaba de decir. OBSERVACIONES: A veces
> se introduce un comentario u objeción a lo que se acaba de decir. 3.
> Se usa cuando se duda, se recuerda algo o se ésta pensando qué decir a
> continuación.
>
> ***ah*** (DEA) interj. 1 Puede expresar diversas emociones esp sorpresa o
> rechazo, a veces denotando que se cae en la cuenta de algo. 2. Precede
> a una advertencia o amenaza. 3. (lit) Seguida de la preposición DE + n
> de lugar, se usa para llamar a los que están en él.
>
> **Mientras que el DRAE se recogían sólo significados de tipo emotivo, en
> estos diccionarios se registra otro tipo de significados,
> principalmente cognitivo e interaccionales.**
>
> ...